# Activating Workflow dynamically

Tags: 2013, workflow

We have two sets of Users:

1. One who (Set **A**) create content directly in Tridion and publish the Components.
2. The other set (Set **B**) use a CoreService driven application (using Workflow) to Publish the content.

Both use the same Schema for creating components. The issues here is **A** users do not want Workflow and **B** users want Workflow on the same Schema. Is this a possible scenario?

Is there any workaround for **A** users (who use Tridion directly to create content) not go through Workflow? (I have already explained that Workflow can either be turned on or off and user sets do not matter). Appreciate any solutions.

Answer (score 5):

You say create but I assume you include update too.

Given you say dynamically I assume you want the workflow associated (and triggering) to be automated.

Catch the Save event. Check the *Set* of the user

- If *Set A* - continue action as designed
- If *Set B* - follow the desired workflow path; you could get fancy and have some sort of pattern to use a specific workflow bundle created for each user

  - this could hold multiple components updated throughout the hour/day/week/whatever until
  - the workflow process is initiated on *that* bundle -

    - in which case a new bundle is started - lots of other variations come to mind - it's down to business/user requirements

I guess another approach may be to have workflow enforced on the Schema. Then the first activity checks to see if the user is *Set A* or *Set B*

- If *Set A* - complete workflow
- If *Set B* - follow the desired workflow path

Comment: For clarity: in general, workflow processes can be started programatically, you don’t need a Bundle per se. So, indeed, an event handler can be used to conditionally start a workflow.

Comment: Good point Rick; my thought with the Bundle was just that I often find people will prefer to pass multiple items through workflow in one go (via a Bundle) rather than one item at a time - and in some instances the business requirement may be to use Bundles (for reasons such as attaching metadata etc.). I should have perhaps highlighted "could get fancy" and noted "and complex if *required* "

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the official [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com) you will find two types of Worklows, implicit and explicit. One is where you directly set a workflow (Process Definition) to a certain Schema and each Component which is created automatically enters said workflow, and the other one relies on Bundles and their workflows which must be started by explicitly. So the solution for your scenario is not to use Worklow for one group of users and use Bundle Worklows for the group of users who need to go through it. You can find more details about these approaches in the aforementioned docs.